# ctrl+shift+tab with Caps Lock as ctrl does not work with xmodmap

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, manjaro, xmodmap

I'm using the following template from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xmodmap

```
clear      lock 
clear   control
clear      mod1
clear      mod2
clear      mod3
clear      mod4
clear      mod5
keycode      37 = Hyper_L
keycode      66 = Control_L
add     control = Control_L Control_R
add        mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R Meta_L
add        mod2 = Num_Lock
add        mod3 = Hyper_L
add        mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add        mod5 = Mode_switch ISO_Level3_Shift
```

but it doesn't recognize ctrl+shift+tab anymore.

Is there a way to solve this?

I'm on Manjaro Linux + Plasma 5.25.5

Thanks!

Comment: So you took `9.4 Turn CapsLock into Control, and LeftControl into Hyper`.  What do you mean by "it doesn't recognize ctrl+shift+tab"? <--You understand that instead of ctrl you now press CapsLock?

Comment: @Andra Yes, when I press (physical CapsLock as ctrl)+shift+tab it doesn't work like ctrl+shift+tab.